# businescard disguised as a real iphone, anoyone knows a good mockup / sample?

Tags: business, iphone

I try to create a businesscard like below. I searched for the internet for an template to no avail. So playing now around with Illustrator but im not that of a design guru. Does anyone know if below image is based on a freely available template / mockup ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[An iOS 4 version.](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/iphone-gui-psd-v4/) I don't believe there are any restrictions on this. You can always check with the creators.

-- Just noticed that they have newer versions --

[An iOS 6 version](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/ios-6-gui-psd-iphone-5/) is available now.

There's plenty more there, just check the right rail.